# Create block content programmatically

Tags: 8, blocks

I've created a custom block type.

I want to create a block with 19 translations programmatically. 
I've seen that you can use Block::create() method...for which I can neither find proper documentation nor examples.
Could anyone provide an example?

Fyi my code is:

```
Block::create([
  'id' => 'my_header_dk',
  'settings' => [
    'id' => 'my_header',
    'label' => 'My header',
    'label_display' => FALSE,
    'provider' => 'my_block',
    'status' => TRUE,
    'langcode' = 'da',
    'icon' => [
      33,
     ],
    'header' => 'This is the header text',
    'link_text' => 'Click here',
    'visibility' => [],
    'region' => 'header',
    'plugin' => 'my_header',
    'theme' => 'my_theme',
    'status' => TRUE,
 ])->save();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create content for the custom block type `basic`:

```
use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent;

$block = BlockContent::create([
  'info' => 'block 1',
  'type' => 'basic',
  'langcode' => 'en',
]);
$block->save();
```

And add a french translation:

```
$french_block = $block->addTranslation('fr', ['info' => 'bloc 1']);
$french_block->save();
```

Custom block types are content, not configuration. See this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218244/47547